# Url format is not happening properly with special character query param value

Tags: android, post, format, urlencode

I am trying with `POST` method Api which has Query params. Among them one query param has a value starts with `*.` Every Query param has appending properly. But only this Query param which starts with special characters is not appending properly.

This is my code

```
                Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri.parse("").buildUpon();
                uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("error", "true");
                uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("type", "dfs_query_then_fetch");
                uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("path", URLEncoder.encode("*.sames.samets._source", "UTF-8"));
                uriBuilder.build();
                String destinationsURL = uriBuilder.toString();

                String url1 = "https://host/template";
                String finalUrl = url1.concat(destinationsURL);
```

From Path Query param value, its not concatinating. Its concatinating like a normal string not as url.

I tried `URLEncoder.encode("","")` , but not working. 
Please some one help on this issue. Any solutions appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I think you should be doing ```Uri.parse("https://host/template").buildUpon()```. I am not too sure but trying to appendQueryParameters with an empty base URL is probably the problem

Comment: @Tom Bailey this is not the base url. For some security reasons I write like host. I am not using Uri.parse("https://host/template").buildUpon()

Comment: Right but what do you expect uriBuilder.toString(); to be if you don't provide a base URL? I think you are expecting it to be "?error=true&..." but I don't think that is a valid URI which is probably why you are running into problems

Comment: * is already in encoded form... encoded value for* is *, ex. for space " " value is %20

Comment: I will provide you the Screen shot of that

Comment: I have edited my description in the above

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Uri` instead of `UrlEncoder` :

```
  val urlEncoded: String = Uri.encode(path); // %20%20*.sames.samets._source

  var urlEncoded =  URLEncoder.encode(path, "UTF-8"); // ++*.sames.samets._source
```

Comment: Sorry..Typo error.. there is no space in queryparam value

Comment: Please c check the above screen shot for your reference. There url format was not correct. last query param was not concatinating properly I think.

Comment: No.. not working same happening like in above screen shot

Comment: are you sure it's not working? cause I don't see any issue in formed url. because even if it is not showing fully blue highlights, that doesn't mean it is not well formatted